# Odd type of a column in a Data Frame

Tags: r

I used to think that a single column in a Data Frame is a Vector.

I have some code below.

In the last line, what does it mean that `typeof(incomeAndState$state)` is `integer`?

```
> income <- c(60, 49, 40, 61, 64, 60, 59, 54, 62, 69, 70, 42, 56,
          61, 61, 61, 58, 51, 48, 65, 49, 49, 41, 48, 52, 46,
          59, 46, 58, 43)
> state <- c("tas", "sa",  "qld", "nsw", "nsw", "nt",  "wa",  "wa",
        "qld", "vic", "nsw", "vic", "qld", "qld", "sa",  "tas",
        "sa",  "nt",  "wa",  "vic", "qld", "nsw", "nsw", "wa",
        "sa",  "act", "nsw", "vic", "vic", "act")
> incomeAndState <- data.frame(state=state, income=income)
> incomeAndState$state
```

Output:

```
[1] tas sa  qld nsw nsw nt  wa  wa  qld vic nsw vic qld qld sa  tas sa  nt  wa  vic qld nsw
[23] nsw wa  sa  act nsw vic vic act
Levels: act nsw nt qld sa tas vic wa


> typeof(incomeAndState$state)
```

Output **(WHAT DOES THIS MEAN?)**:

```
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: That is because `class(incomeAndState$state)` is `factor` and they are stored as integers internally.

Comment: It's a factor; `is.factor(incomeAndState$state)` will return `TRUE`. Or see `str(incomeAndState)` to see the type of all the dataframe's columns.

Comment: @RonakShah Upvoted, thanks. If you make a separate answer I'll mark it as correct. Question: am I correct in saying that a column of a Data Frame is a Vector? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Typically each column of a `data.frame` is a vector, yes. It is feasible, though, to have "list-columns", something often used in (for example) `tidyr::nest`.

Comment: @camille Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state` column is a factor.

```
class(incomeAndState$state)
#[1] "factor"
```

and factors are internally stored as integers hence you see

```
typeof(incomeAndState$state)
#[1] "integer"
```

which can also be verified with `mode`

```
mode(incomeAndState$state)
#[1] "numeric"
```

This can be avoided if you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while constructing the dataframe

```
incomeAndState <- data.frame(state=state, income=income, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

which will give you

```
typeof(incomeAndState$state)
#[1] "character"

mode(incomeAndState$state)
#[1] "character"
```